# How to fetch to localhost with Next.js on a different domain? [deployed]

Tags: next.js, cors, fetch, cross-domain

I have a project in Next.js where the frontend needs to make requests to the local network or localhost regardless of whether the project is running locally or on Vercel, as the system I developed controls smart cameras, and these cameras have an API, just connect them to the LOCAL NETWORK and make requests to their IP, for example: `http://192.168.1.108/cgi-bin/snapshot.cgi?channel=1`. Note that the address starts with "HTTP" and not "HTTPS", this is because it is a local network.

My current problem is: When my Next project is running on the local network, it can request the camera APIs without any problem, BUT WHEN I deploy the project to Vercel, it is no longer possible to request the camera API via Safari and gives an origin error, the error that appears in the console is: `Fetch API cannot load http://192.168.1.108/cgi-bin/snapshot.cgi?channel=1 due to access control checks.`. Note that both the camera server that I am trying to request and my project in next have Cors Origin for any host, follow my code example from the next.config.js file:

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  async headers() {
    return [
      {
        // matching all API routes
        source: "/api/:path*",
        headers: [
          { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", value: "true" },
          { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", value: "*" }, // replace this your actual origin
          { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", value: "GET,DELETE,PATCH,POST,PUT" },
          { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", value: "X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version" },
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```